# chainlink contract doesn't call the fulfill() function that received after the response

Tags: api, solidity, response, chainlink

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ChainlinkClient.sol";
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/ConfirmedOwner.sol";

contract FetchFromArray is ChainlinkClient, ConfirmedOwner {
    using Chainlink for Chainlink.Request;

    string public id="before";
    string public test="4";

    bytes32 private jobId;
    uint256 private fee;

    event RequestFirstId(bytes32 indexed requestId, string id);

    constructor() ConfirmedOwner(msg.sender) {
        setChainlinkToken(0x326C977E6efc84E512bB9C30f76E30c160eD06FB);
        setChainlinkOracle(0x40193c8518BB267228Fc409a613bDbD8eC5a97b3);
        jobId = "7d80a6386ef543a3abb52817f6707e3b";
        fee = (1 * LINK_DIVISIBILITY) / 10; // 0,1 * 10**18 (Varies by network and job)
    }

    function requestFirstId() public returns (bytes32 requestId) {
        Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest(
            jobId,
            address(this),
            this.fulfill.selector
        );

        req.add(
            "get",
            "https://site.api.espn.com/apis/site/v2/sports/basketball/nba/summary?event=401541181"
        );
        req.add("path", "header,gameNote"); 

        return sendChainlinkRequest(req, fee);
    }

    function fulfill(
        bytes32 _requestId,
        string memory _id
    ) public recordChainlinkFulfillment(_requestId) {
        emit RequestFirstId(_requestId, _id);
        id = _id;
        test="2";
    }

    function withdrawLink() public onlyOwner {
        LinkTokenInterface link = LinkTokenInterface(chainlinkTokenAddress());
        require(
            link.transfer(msg.sender, link.balanceOf(address(this))),
            "Unable to transfer"
        );
    }
}
```

I tested on sepolia testnet(eth) and mumbai(polygon).

I also proceeded with other API requests and checked the req.add ('path',~) well.

Jobid also confirmed through the document.

However, the contract fulfill() was not called.

Several other successful API requests have been confirmed to be successful.
The only difference is that large responses to failed requests appear to fail.

However, regarding the response size, it could not be confirmed through the document. Therefore, the exact cause is unknown.

The ChainlinkRequested event is confirmed, but the id and test variables do not change.

i tested on remix

Comment: Have you tested it against the config present in the Large Responses section? https://docs.chain.link/any-api/get-request/examples/large-responses